# MMLoadDrv apart of Catalyst Control Center? Look suspicious

Tags: malware, spyware, display-driver, amd-catalyst

This loads at startup every once in a while. It looks strange, and it's always the same image in that window, but it's slightly animated.

Does anybody know the purpose of this? Can I remove it? I've heard it's related to CCC.

Screenshot:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MMLoadDrv.exe` is part of your driver set and nothing to be worried about.

If this is annoying, you could try to reinstall your graphic drivers.

In addition, or if reinstalling does not help, you could use software like [Spybot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/mirrors/) (free) to check and modify your start-up programs and services.

Comment: Re-installing CCC and the drivers seemed to at least make this loading form invisible.